# Chart js using Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts

hi i have this json result

```
[{"date":"1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM","Count":2},
{"date":"1/2/2020 12:00:00 AM","Count":1},
{"date":"1/3/2020 12:00:00 AM","Count":0},
{"date":"1/4/2020 12:00:00 AM","Count":0}]
```

and i have simple chart using chart js.
How do i able to do the same but using my json result
the X is the date and the Y is the Count.

using this.

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
      labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Earnings",
      lineTension: 0.3,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)",
      borderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointRadius: 3,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      data: [0, 10000, 5000, 15000, 10000, 20000, 15000, 25000, 20000, 30000, 25000, 40000],
    }],
  },
```

Sorry i'm just new at JS.
Hope someone help me out .
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can use create fiddle the share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope with help you.

```js
var jsonfile = {
  "jsonarray": [{
      "date": "1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM",
      "Count": 2
    },
    {
      "date": "1/2/2020 12:00:00 AM",
      "Count": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "1/3/2020 12:00:00 AM",
      "Count": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "1/4/2020 12:00:00 AM",
      "Count": 0
    }
  ]
};

var labels = jsonfile.jsonarray.map(function(e) {
  return e.date;
});
var data = jsonfile.jsonarray.map(function(e) {
  return e.Count;
});;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Earnings",
      lineTension: 0.3,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)",
      borderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointRadius: 3,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,

      data: data,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.3)'
    }]
  }
};

var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Are you missing 'jsonarray' inside of the array 'jsonfile '